# how to replace unicode "&aring" with norwegian character å

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to replace the unicode: `&aring` with Norwegian character `å` but the following code is not helping:

```
[unq1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&aring;" withString:@"å" ];
```

Comment: Can you show string `unq1`?

Comment: How exactly is it not helping?

Comment: it is printing----->  N&aring;r det bl <-------   in the console and the code above is not replacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working perfectly on my side, may be the problem is you have not save the result of this `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method. So try like this

```
unq1 = [unq1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&aring;" withString:@"å"];
```

Comment: I am sorry to make such a silly mistake have to learn objective c basics once again.. Thanks anyway